# Making sure AddMonths works irrespective of any culture

Tags: c#, windows, datetime

I've a date in string format:"28/09/2012" in my C# program.It could be in "09/28/2012" format as well.
I need to convert this string to DateTime and then invoke AddMonths(2) method on it.
How do I make sure that this code works without error on a machine with any cultureie.UK/US/Asia etc?

Comment: Why do you expect `AddMonths` to ever error? Why do you believe it is culture dependant? What errors have you seen that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: There is no universal way to do this unless you know in advance whether the format is dd/mm or mm/dd: consider date "10/09/2012", you can't know if it's 10th september or 09th october, unless you know the culture.

Comment: OK.Thanks.Assuming that the format is "28/09/2012", how do I achieve this functionality please?

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.Parse should have an overload that takes a CultureInfo.

You should pass the culture info of your choice. The one installed on the machine or maybe the one selected by the user in your application options or configuration etc.

Once you have the DateTime, AddMonths should work regardless of culture.

Sorry for not being more precise with the exact overload, I'm not in front of Visual Studio right now.

Answer (score 1):

`AddMonths` is not what would fail if you specify a wrong culture for `DateTime.Parse`. So you must know in which culture or format the DtaeTime-String is. Otherwise it's impossible to know whether "10/09/2012" is in september or october(as František Žiačik has pointed out).

> Assuming that the format is "28/09/2012", how do I achieve this functionality

If you know that the inpout string is always in that format "dd/MM/yyyy", then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` and apply the correct culture to `ToString` afterwards:

```
String input = "28/09/2012";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
CultureInfo targetCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
String output = dt.AddMonths(2).ToString( targetCulture );
```

[**Demo here**](http://ideone.com/P4Na5K)